# Laravel Horizon getting empty Dashboard Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, horizon

I installed a **Horizon 5.14.1** in **Laravel 9.36.2**

But when im gonna acess a dashboard i got this error

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token** (at app.js?id=766b568d1924aa83b2a1f279d2c5ab9e:2:484352)

But in the console, `php artisan horizon` this works.

Someone can help me?

[image]

Comment: Did you correctly run `php artisan horizon:install` once updated? Also, leave the console open, right click on the refresh button and click on the last option "Empty cache and hard reload"

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working ( laravel/webpack/horizon )

Comment: @SachaDurand what? You are not the author of the question, if you have a similar question, post it please